# Утечка памяти с сервера

Tags: apache, память, php, debian

На сервере запущен апач, на котором крутятся порядка пары десятков сайтов. Периодически начинает исчезать свободная память. Уменьшается она постепенно, но за пару недель может выйти в ноль, после чего требуется перезагружать сервер. Как найти и обезвредить виновника?

Answer (score 2):

1. Уменьшить время жизни процессов: MaxRequestsPerChild.
2. Ограничить их количество: ServerLimit.
3. Если этот сервер отдаёт статику, позволить делать несколько запросов к одному процессу, увеличив время связи с клиентом: Keep-Alive.
4. Добавить в crontab регулярную незаметную перезагрузку: параметр -graceful.